# How to install clang header files?

Tags: c++

I have clang installed on my MacOS (in /usr/bin/clang ) which I think comes installed by default on Mac, however, when I try to include clang header files in a script, it says they are not found

```
Example.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'clang/Driver/Options.h' file not found
```

Question: is it necessary (and possible, if so, how) to install the header files when clang is already installed and built on the MacOS system (or does clang itself need to be reinstalled at the same time as all the desired development tooling packages and their header files are installed)?

```
#include "clang/Driver/Options.h"
#include "clang/AST/AST.h"
#include "clang/AST/ASTContext.h"
#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/ASTConsumers.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
#include "clang/Rewrite/Core/Rewriter.h"
```

Comment: You need to install the clang development package(s) to get the various tooling headers.

Comment: In particular, installing llvm through homebrew might be necessary (cannot confirm)

Comment: @G.M. ok, thank you.   Is it possible to install those packages to work with the clang that comes installed with the Mac O.S. system (or do they need to be installed at the same time as clang?

Comment: Have you looked if `/usr/include/clang` is in your directory?

Comment: @Amadeus which directory are you referring to? not sure what you mean when you ask if it is "in your directory"?

Comment: @Leahcim Asking in another way, do you know where (which directory) `clang/Driver/Options.h` is installed in your system? If you do not know, you can use `find` to try to locate it

Comment: @Amadeus yes, I found it `clang/Driver/Options.h` (I did a test install of LLVM in the cloud and found it, but it's not installed by default on my Mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asked if it was necessary and possible to install the header files on MacOS which comes with clang installed already.  The desired header files weren't installed and in order to install them it is possible to clone the repo and build llvm and clang (as described in the llvm getting started guide http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html) , so that it's in effect installed twice on the system.

Comment: Even if you do get the headers, those clang headers depend on static libs not found in a default installation of macOS. So, while you do get clang installed twice by building the LLVM+clang source tree (although I suppose the binary in /usr/local/bin gets overwritten with the newly built clang binary), you also get a bunch of `.a` files that you need.

Answer (score 3):

When you use **double quotes** for including the libraries it will search the current directory which your c/cpp file or application resides in. Try with **<** and **>**  or compile with the **-I** option